# Initializing an integer member variable results in changing another member variable's address

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb, segmentation-fault

This seems like a fairly strange bug to me. My C++ program is segfaulting, and I found something strange using GDB. I have the following constructor and copy constructor:

```
Bank::Bank(char mode, int floor_dimensions_, int num_floors_) : floor_dimensions(floor_dimensions_), num_floors(num_floors_) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_floors; i++) {
        floors[i] = new Floor(floor_dimensions);
    }

    if (mode == 'M') {
        read_map(floors);
    } else if (mode == 'C') {
        read_coords(floors);
    }
}

Bank::Bank(const Bank& b) {
    floor_dimensions = b.floor_dimensions;
    num_floors = b.num_floors;

    cout << floor_dimensions << endl;
    cout << num_floors << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_floors; i++) {
        floors[i] = new Floor(*b.floors[i]);
        floors[i]->print_map();
}
```

The definition of this class is something like

```
class Bank {
    /** The number of floors the bank has */
    int num_floors;

    /** The dimension of each of the floors */
    int floor_dimensions;

    /** The floors in the bank */
    Floor* floors[];

private:
    Bank(char mode, int floor_dimensions_, int num_floors_);
    Bank(const Bank& bank);
    ~Bank();
    void read_map(Floor** floor);
void read_coords(Floor** floor);
}
```

Now I set a breakpoint at the first line of the constructor using GDB. After executing the next two lines, the value of b.floors[1] has changed, which leads to the segfault when I call `b.floors[i]->foo()`.

```
    Breakpoint 1, Bank::Bank (this=0x7fffffffe050, b=...) at bank.cpp:29
29      floor_dimensions = b.floor_dimensions;
(gdb) p b.floors[0]
$4 = (Floor *) 0x610070
(gdb) p b.floors[1]
$5 = (Floor *) 0x6103f0
(gdb) p b.floors[2]
$6 = (Floor *) 0x610770
(gdb) n
30      num_floors = b.num_floors;
(gdb) p b.floors[0]
$7 = (Floor *) 0x610070
(gdb) p b.floors[1]
$8 = (Floor *) 0x8006103f0
(gdb) p b.floors[2]
$9 = (Floor *) 0x610770
(gdb) n
32      cout << floor_dimensions << endl;
(gdb) p b.floors[0]
$10 = (Floor *) 0x610070
(gdb) p b.floors[1]
$11 = (Floor *) 0x800000003
(gdb) p b.floors[2]
$12 = (Floor *) 0x610770
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: `Floor* floors[];` is invalid syntax. Also you're not copying the array so you're probably deallocating the same pointer every time an object is destroyed.

Comment: @SethCarnegie How would I create an array of pointers then? And also I didn't put the code to copy the array on purpose.

Comment: Why did you omit the array copying code? That's the most likely source of the error!

Comment: Also - why are calling foo() on the source - since this is missing from the class decl

Comment: @AdrianCornish Where am I modifying it?

AndrewShepherd The code crashes the way I've provided it, where foo is any function (even an empty one).

Comment: @gsingh2011 Noticed that - updated comment - you have old version

Comment: The code doesn't *compile* the way you provided it, much less crash.

Comment: @WhozCraig What part are you referring to?

Comment: Please supply the code of the other constructor. Also note that this will always crash when you attempt to copy a copy.

Comment: As Seth pointed out, your Floors* [] syntax is invalid, and even if it were, we have no definition of what a Floor is as you did not provide the class definition or code. The array copy code is missing, and likely the root of your error. Post something that we can look at besides half-code and conjecture and you're issue will probably solve itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is most likely the fact that you are attempting to access an uninitialized pointer (`b.floors`). Assuming `b` was a result of this copy constructor, then `b.floors` will be pointing to random memory. `b.floors[i]` will then be pointing to random memory some bytes ahead of what `b.floors` is pointing to, and eventually you use `->` to dereference this random address, which causes a segmentation fault.

The solution to your problem is to properly allocate and copy the floors array:

```
floors = new Floor* [num_floors];
for (int i=0; i<num_floors; ++i)
  floors[i] = b.floors[i];
```

You may also want to copy the pointed object `Floor`, depending on the details of your implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I was initializing floors by looping through and calling new floor() without first doing `floors = new Floor*[num_floors];` Also, the code you gave me, `floors = new (Floor*) [num_floors];` gives the compile error `bank.cpp:36:23: error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id
bank.cpp:36:23: note: try removing the parentheses around the type-id`